# Wordpress auto encoding ampersands in only one environment

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, character-encoding, acfpro

I'm not much of a server guy so I was wondering if anyone here would know of a basic apache/mysql configuration detail to look for to explain why a cloned wordpress site in one environment would be encoding all ampersands on save when the same site in several other environments doesn't. There's not a whole lot special about the code. It's pretty much raw wordpress and ACF for custom fields.

I'm sure it's not just ampersands too, but that's the character we're using to test with. And really, what is happening is a site we built on our local machines was hosted on media temple, then aws, then wpengine, and now liquid web. All previous hosts have had no issues with this, but now with liquid web we have an encoding problem and they insist this is unrelated to their server configurations, and refuse to help diagnose the issue.

I can run phpinfo() on my local and the liquid web servers, but I am not sure what I would be looking for. Anything that would be auto encoding post values? Not sure. Also not sure if this would be a mysql configuration thing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, we found the culprit minutes after posting this. Here it is in case anyone else has this issue:

in the wp-config.php file we noticed this:

```
define('CUSTOM_TAGS', true);
```

Evidently, this runs the wp_kses function on post input. We didn't add this to the config file, but considering plugins can modify this file, it is plausible that we had tried out plugins for things and decided against them, and upon uninstall, the plugin didn't clean up after itself.

Who knows how this can end up in the wp-config.php file, but it did. So if you experience the &amp;amp; bug, have a look there.